# Group by and Max are not working for this issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table

```
ID      Date     Indicator
12345   1/1/2001   N
12345   2/1/2001   N
12345   3/1/2001   N
12345   4/1/2001   Y
12345   5/1/2001   Y
12345   6/1/2001   Y
67891   2/1/2002   N
67891   3/1/2002   N
67891   4/1/2002   Y
67891   5/1/2002   Y
67891   6/1/2002   Y
```

I want to pull the first rows where Indicator is changes for example

```
ID      Date     Indicator
12345   1/1/2001   N
12345   4/1/2001   Y
67891   2/1/2002   N
67891   4/1/2002   Y
```

and only second row where indicator changed

```
ID      Date     Indicator
12345   4/1/2001   Y
67891   4/1/2002   Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Three step solution using analytical function is shown below.
I assume your table is TEST

```
-- add IS_CHANG E= 'Y' for change in Indicator
with test1 as (
select a.*,
case when lag(indicator,1,'X') over (partition by ID order by date_d) != indicator then 'Y' end as is_change
from test a),
-- filter changes only and numerate records
test2 as (
select a.*,
row_number() over (partition by id order by date_d) as RN
from test1 a
where is_change = 'Y')
-- get only 2nd change
select ID, DATE_D, INDICATOR from test2
where rn = 2
;
```